# html/css columns

Tags: html, css

I keep reading that you can use html/css columns without using them in a table.  The www.w3schools.org site shows that you can, but I can't get it to work out at all in my code.  basically I have this idea.

```
      <div container="name">
         <dl>item 1 </dl>
         <dd>explain</dd>
         <dl>item 2 </dl>
         <dd>explain</dl>
         ...
      </div>
```

What I need is for the container to have three columns and the section with the detailed list to be two columns than I will put the info for the third column in its own column.  I know the column span is the best way to keep that separate, but I can't find any good explanations for this.  And I can't get it to work out of my css page or html page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going about it the wrong way. Try this.

**html:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left-col">
        <!-- left column -->
    </div>
    <div id="content-col">
        <!-- content column -->
    </div>
    <div id="right-col">
        <!-- left column -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#container { overflow: hidden; width: 940px; }
#left-col { float: left; width: 200px; margin-right: 20px; }
#content-col { float: left; width: 500px; }
#right-col { float: right; width: 200px; }
```

**demo** - http://jsfiddle.net/gk5vD/

FYI - you misunderstood what a `dl` is, have a look at http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/dl/

Comment: i used one div container as the container is to have three columns inside it.  And the dl list is really just a place holder, it will have a small image, name, and comment per "list item".  There is two side columns of those then a third column on the right that will act like page nav. I am trying to use columns to hold it into one div container as page sizes change and I want them to stay centered.

Comment: I ended up putting them each in the container.  Then making the container wide enough to hold them all, and making two float lefts, and a float right.  THANK YOU for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please don't use w3schools. `</rant>`

CSS3 has columns built in. Have a read about it [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_multi-column_layouts).